# Git checkout remote bare repo to an older branch

Tags: git, deployment, web-deployment

I'm currently testing out deploying websites via Git and am having trouble understanding the following:

Currently, I have a bare remote repo on my DEV environment with a post-receive hook which sets GIT_WORK_TREE to my webroot. I push to there from my local repo with syntax like 'git push DEV master'. This works great. However, I also have a 'develop' branch which I push to DEV (the post-receive hook is set to 'git checkout -f [BRANCH_NAME]) and this also works great.

My question is for the following situation: let's say that I find a bug on DEV (pushed from 'develop' branch) but I don't have time to fix it (maybe there is a client review that day). I would love to be able to do a 'git push DEV master' (the master branch has the last bug-free push to DEV and is an ancestor of the develop commit currently on DEV) and be done with it. But, when I do this, the remote repo tells me 'Everything is up to date!' I suppose that makes sense, but what I would like to do is force git to take the push from 'master' branch and fire the post-receive hook anyway, which is necessary for proper deployment of web assets.

I tried going directly to the remote repo in ssh and attempting to checkout master from there, but it tells me I need a work tree to do this (because it's bare, I assume).

What is the correct method of doing this? I'd like to avoid doing a revert or rebase if possible, but maybe that's the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> , but what I would like to do is force git to take the push from
>   'master' branch and fire the post-receive hook anyway, which is
>   necessary for proper deployment of web assets.

The problem is that you have already pushed the changes to your remote, so there's nothing to push.  Your options include:

- force a change in your local branch...e.g., by updating a serial number in a file, committing, and pushing.
- just running the `post-receive` hook on the server by hand, filling in the necessary environment variables.

Going to the remote repository and trying to checkout the master branch should work, provided you have both a repository and a working tree (possibly by setting `GIT_WORK_TREE` yourself).  However, this isn't going to trigger your `post-receive` hook, so you'll need to manually take care of any additional logic that's there.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I will wait a bit to see if there are any other suggestions but I will definitely try these out tonight.

Comment: You were totally right about GIT_WORK_TREE btw; for others who may want to do the same thing in a remote repo where the work tree is separate from the repo itself, use the following syntax from your .git directory: GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/work/tree git checkout [branch_name]

Answer (score 0):

Use tags. For instance tag your current deployed version as 'current', push this tag and let your post-receive-hook act on this tag.

```
#!/bin/sh
read oldrev newrev refname
```

$refname now contains /revs/tags/current and $newrev contains the hash of the tagged commit. To change to a different revision delete the 'current' tag and set it elsewhere and push the tag. This way you don't need to make dummy changes in your files.

Comment: cool, thank you, I will try this approach the next time I am in this situation